# Scene Eventhandler: bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_[pre|post]

Tags: python

In a quite large addon I have enabled some event handlers to check some things and everything works fine so far. But I'm struggling a bit with scene updates. They get triggered continuously and repeating relatively fast even if nothing obviously (like deleting an object) is changed in the current scene. Even if the mouse didn't move they get triggered multiple times in a second (I'm assuming something with draw cycles is happening here or some kind of time properties in the scene got changed).

I would like to know if this is an expected behaviour and how to determine if something of interest is happening? My goal is to hook in if a camera, a light, an object  or a material has changed (if possible without iterating over many or all objects). Thx.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58663/horrible-scene-update-post-performance)  Those handlers are called upwards of 2000 times per second.  I recall seeing something about this being looked into for 2.8.  I would look into running a modal timer operator (see templates for example) that you can turn on and off with boolean property update.  [Example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/69599/15543)

Comment: @batFINGER Puh! Than this EventHandler is **useless** and I can't understand why it exists for sripting. Anyway, the [Relatet](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58663/horrible-scene-update-post-performance) link has some good information. Thx.